# Webpack bundling a library that uses another library that contains WebAssembly gives several files as output, but the paths to them are not relative

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm making a custom element using Svelte, that I plan to publish to NPM as a library. The component uses a library I made, that uses WebAssembly. When I build the Svelte library with Webpack, it gives me three files.

- 1.1.js
- [hash].wasm
- bundle.js

`bundle.js` references both the wasm file and `1.1.js`. This works in the project folder itself, but when I `npm pack` it and try to use it in another project, it can't find the `1.1.js` file or the wasm file. Apparently, the paths are relative to the *website root* instead of eg. `/1.1.js` instead of `node_modules/packageName/1.1.js`. I really have no clue how to fix this. Any ideas?

The start of my webpack config file looks like this:

```
const config: webpack.Configuration & WebpackDevServer.Configuration = {
    entry: {
        bundle: [
            './src/main.ts',
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            // Note: Additional aliases will be loaded automatically from `tsconfig.compilerOptions.paths`
            svelte: path.resolve('node_modules', 'svelte'),
        },
        extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.ts', '.svelte'],
        mainFields: ['svelte', 'browser', 'module', 'main'],
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/build',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].[id].js',
    },
    ...
```

I have tried both importing the `bundle.js` directly with HTML, and importing the package using `import x from y` syntax in a JavaScript file, and running Webpack on the project that uses the Svelte component. I get errors such as this  `ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 1 failed. (error: http://localhost:8080/1.1.js)`